# Добавление блокнoта в автозапуск через реестр

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, реестр

```
from winreg import *

# Путь в реестре
key_my = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
                 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\\CurrentVersion\Run')
# Установить программу "notepad" в автозагрузку
SetValueEx(key_my, 'mynotepad', 0, REG_SZ, 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe')
# Закрыть реестр
CloseKey(key_my)
```

Запускаю этот скрипт в cmd от Администратора, но выдаёт мне

> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе.

Как мне снять это ограничение?

Answer (score 1):

Решение.

```
from winreg import *

# Путь в реестре
key_my = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
                 r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', 
                 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
# Установить программу "notepad" в автозагрузку
SetValueEx(key_my, 'mynotepad', 0, REG_SZ, r'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe')
# Закрыть реестр
CloseKey(key_my)
```

Данным способом можно любую программу, скрипт прописать в реестр и оно, в конкретном случае программа "notepad" будет стартовать после загрузки Windows.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать raw-strings для windows-путей: `r'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe'` -- это упрощает запись, убирая необходимость экранирования обратного слеша.