# Автодобавление скрипта в автозагрузчик

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловая-система

Что можно написать в скрипте для автоматического добавления его в автозагрузчик?
Если что это должно работать в виде exe'шника

Comment: В реестр запиши

Comment: С этого места поподробнее

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483144/16574

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777576/16574

Comment: погуглить попробуй)